# Call a script when a button has being clicked using Jquery's .Click() function

Tags: jquery, frontend

I have two buttons to hide/display checkboxes, so I have written this jquery script to change the button colour/hide/show onClick.

My problem is that no matter what button I click on my page the function is called.

From what I have read I understood the `if ($("#btnToLet, #btnSale").click())` (I have also tried `if ($("#btnToLet").click() || $("#btnSale").click())`), would take care of that issue, but it does not

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#btnToLet, #btnSale").click()) {
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            alert(e.target.id + ' clicked');
            $("#lblGasSafety").toggleClass("hidden");
            $("#lblElectricalReport").toggleClass("hidden");
            $("#btnSale").toggleClass("btn-info");
            $("#btnToLet").toggleClass("btn-info");
        });
    }
});
```

```
<div class="form-group">
<button id="btnSale" type="button" class="saleTypes btn btn-info">Sale</button>
<button id="btnToLet" type="button" class="saleTypes btn btn-default">To Let</button>
<label id="lblGasSafety" class="checkbox-inline hidden">
    <input type="checkbox">Gas Safety
</label>
<label id="lblElectricalReport" class="checkbox-inline hidden">
    <input type="checkbox">Electrical Report
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need define Handler for elements

```
$("#btnToLet, #btnSale").click(function (e) {
            alert(e.target.id + ' clicked');
            $("#lblGasSafety").toggleClass("hidden");
            $("#lblElectricalReport").toggleClass("hidden");
            $("#btnSale").toggleClass("btn-info");
            $("#btnToLet").toggleClass("btn-info");
});
```